# Find optimal points to cut a set of intervals

Tags: algorithm, optimization, time-complexity, scheduling, integer-programming

Given a set of intervals on the real line and some parameter d > 0. Find a sequence of points with gaps between neighbors less or equal to d, such that the number of intervals that contain any of the points is minimized. 
To prevent trivial solutions we ask that the first point from the sequence is before the first interval, and the last point is after the last interval. The intervals can be thought of right-open.

Does this problem have a name? Maybe even an algorithm and a complexity bound?

*Some background:* 
This is motivated by a question from topological data analysis, but it seems so general, that it could be interesting for other topics, e.g. task scheduling (given a factory that has to shut down at least once a year and wants to minimize the number of tasks inflicted by the maintenance...)
We were thinking of [integer programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) and [minimum cuts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_cut), but the d-parameter does not quite fit. We also implemented approximate greedy solutions in n^2 and n*logn time, but they can run into very bad local optima.

*Show me a picture*

I draw intervals by lines. The following diagram shows 7 intervals. d is such that you have to cut at least every fourth character. At the bottom of the diagram you see two solutions (marked with x and y) to the diagram. x cuts through the four intervals in the top, whereas y cuts through the three intervals at the bottom. y is optimal.

```
 ——— ———
 ——— ———
   ———
   ———
   ———
x x   x x
y   y   y
```

*Show me some code:*
How should we define `fun` in the following snippet?

```py
intervals = [(0, 1), (0.5, 1.5), (0.5, 1.5)]
d = 1.1
fun(intervals, d)
>>> [-0.55, 0.45, 1.55]  # Or something close to it
```

In this small example the optimal solution will cut the first interval, but not the second and third. Obviously, the algorithm should work with more complicated examples as well.

A tougher test can be the following: Given a uniform distribution of interval start times on [0, 100] and lengths uniform on [0, d], one can compute the expected number of cuts by a regular grid [0, d, 2d, 3d,..] to be slightly below 0.5*n. And the optimal solution should be better:

```py
n = 10000
delta = 1
starts = np.random.uniform(low=0., high=99, size=n)
lengths = np.random.uniform(low=0., high=1, size=n)
rand_intervals = np.array([starts, starts + lengths]).T
regular_grid = np.arange(0, 101, 1)
optimal_grid = fun(rand_intervals)

# This computes the number of intervals being cut by one of the points
def cuts(intervals, grid):
    bins = np.digitize(intervals, grid)
    return sum(bins[:,0] != bins[:,1])

cuts(rand_intervals, regular_grid)
>>> 4987  # Expected to be slightly below 0.5*n
assert cuts(rand_intervals, optimal_grid) <= cuts(rand_intervals, regular_grid)
```

Comment: I assumed non-overlapping intervals because of your factory analogy, so I deleted my answer.

Comment: I believe adding a diagram will improve the understanding of the question.

Comment: Added a simple ASCII-artsy diagram. Hopefully it will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this optimally through dynamic programming by maintaining an array `S[k]` where `S[k]` is the best solution (covers the largest amount of space) while having `k` intervals with a point in it. Then you can repeatedly remove your lowest `S[k]`, extend it in all possible ways (limiting yourself to the relevant endpoints of intervals plus the last point in `S[k]` + delta), and updating `S` with those new possible solutions.
When the lowest possible `S[k]` in your table covers the entire range, you are done.

A Python 3 solution using `intervaltree` from pip:

```py
from intervaltree import Interval, IntervalTree

def optimal_points(intervals, d, epsilon=1e-9):
    intervals = [Interval(lr[0], lr[1]) for lr in intervals]
    tree = IntervalTree(intervals)
    start = min(iv.begin for iv in intervals)
    stop = max(iv.end for iv in intervals)

    # The best partial solution with k intervals containing a point.
    # We also store the intervals that these points are contained in as a set.
    sols = {0: ([start], set())}

    while True:
        lowest_k = min(sols.keys())
        s, contained = sols.pop(lowest_k)
        # print(lowest_k, s[-1])  # For tracking progress in slow instances.
        if s[-1] >= stop:
            return s

        relevant_intervals = tree[s[-1]:s[-1] + d]
        relevant_points = [iv.begin - epsilon for iv in relevant_intervals]
        relevant_points += [iv.end + epsilon for iv in relevant_intervals]
        extensions = {s[-1] + d} | {p for p in relevant_points if s[-1] < p < s[-1] + d}

        for ext in sorted(extensions, reverse=True):
            new_s = s + [ext]
            new_contained = set(tree[ext]) | contained
            new_k = len(new_contained)
            if new_k not in sols or new_s[-1] > sols[new_k][0][-1]:
                sols[new_k] = (new_s, new_contained)
```

Comment: That looks promising. Still, something is not as I would expect it to be
Check the following example, which is similar to the one given in the description. I think the solution will cut the last two intervals, whereas it would be optimal to cut the first one.

optimal_points([(0,1),(.5,1.5),(.5,1.5)], d=1.1)
>>> [0, 1.1, 2.2]

Comment: @Arkadi My solution does not support duplicate identical intervals as I use sets to count the number of intervals intersected. Note that the input `[(0, 1), (0.5, 1.5), (0.50001, 1.5)]` does not have this issue.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Passes my test now :) I was also asking for a complexity bound. Assuming there are not too many empty sections (which would make the problem irrelevant), it seems this is O(n*p) where n is the number of intervals and p<=n is the maximal number of intervals that touch any [x, x+d]. Do you agree?

Comment: @Arkadi That's almost right, it's `O(p*n*log(n))` because also have an interval tree query in the inner loop. You can solve the uniqueness issue if you can find an alternative for `intervaltree` that supports getting back some unique identifier for each interval rather than the intervals themselves. It's not a fundamental issue and the algorithm is unchanged. In a total degenerate case where all intervals overlap eachother I think the algorithm becomes O(n^3).

Answer (score 0):

If the range and precision could be feasible for iterating over, we could first merge and count the intervals. For example,

```
[(0, 1), (0.5, 1.5), (0.5, 1.5)] ->
  [(0, 0.5, 1), (0.5, 1, 3), (1, 1.5, 2)]
```

Now let `f(n, k)` represent the optimal solution with `k` points up to `n` on the number line. Then:

```
f(n, k) = min(
  num_intervals(n) + f(n - i, k - 1)
)

num_intervals(n) is known in O(1)
  from a pointer in the merged interval list.

n-i is not every precision point up to n. Rather, it's
every point not more than d back that marks a change
from one merged interval to the next as we move it
back from our current pointer in the merged-interval
list.
```

One issue to note is that we need to store the distance between the rightmost and previous point for any optimal `f(n, k)`. This is to avoid joining `f(n - i, k - 1)` where the second to rightmost point would be less than `d` away from our current `n`, making the new middle point, `n - i`, superfluous and invalidating this solution. (I'm not sure I've thought this issue through enough. Perhaps someone could point out something that's amiss.)

How would we know `k` is high enough? Given that the optimal solution may be lower than the current `k`, we assume that the recurrence would prevent us from finding an instance based on the idea in the above paragraph:

```
0.......8
 ——— ———
 ——— ———
   ———
   ———
   ———
x x   x x
y   y   y

d = 4
merged list:
[(1, 3, 2), (3, 4, 5), (4, 5, 3), (5, 6, 5), (6, 8, 2)]

f(4, 2) = (3, 0) // (intersections, previous point)
f(8, 3) = (3, 4)

There are no valid solutions for f(8, 4) since the
break point we may consider between interval change
in the merged list is before the second-to-last
point in f(8, 3).
```